# XNA: A list that I update every frame seems to lose its first few entries

Tags: c#, .net, list, xna

I have a `List<int>` that I update on every `Update()` call by calling `Add()` to add another integer to that list

On every call to `Draw()`, I `foreach` on that `List` and use the stored `int` to draw something to the screen.

The problem I have is that the for the first few frames (i.e. few calls to Update), my List is out of sync. The stuff I added never shows up.

I added some tracing to file with this code:

```
log.WriteLine("start list with count " + Actions.Count);
int nextAction = getNextAction(); // right now this is just some additions
Actions.Add(nextAction);
movelog.WriteLine("end list with count " + Actions.Count);
```

I get this trace:

```
start list with count 0
end list with count 1

start list with count 0
end list with count 1

start list with count 0
end list with count 1

start list with count 0
end list with count 1

start list with count 0
end list with count 1

start list with count 1
end list with count 2

start list with count 2
end list with count 3

start list with count 3
end list with count 4
```

As you can see for the first few calls to this section of the code (i.e. calls to `Update()`), I add to the list and then the next time it's called it's magically gone as if nothing was added to the list. After the fifth time it finally works. This is pretty consistent across runs.

I tried locking on the list object, and I get the exact same behavior.

What is going on with my code? I'm stumped. I'm not doing anything in parallel and I tried tracing the `ManagedThreadId` every time I add to the list and the thread id is the same.

Comment: If that's how simple the code is, are you sure that `Actions` is a `List<int>`? It might be some other collection type. Like `HashSet` maybe?

Comment: @IIan definite:

        private List<int> _actions;
        public List<int> Actions 
        { 
            get 
            {
                lock (_actions)
                {
                    return _actions;
                }
            } 
        }

Comment: Maybe you're creating a new list and assigning it to `_actions` multiple times. Set breakpoint(s) at where you assign to `_actions`.

Comment: @IlianPinzon tried it. It's only created/initialized once - in the constructor of my class. I added a breakpoint there as well and it was only hit once.

Also as soon as I put a breakpoint at the place where I add to Actions, this doesn't repro. I.e. if I slow it down, it works fine.

Comment: Just out of curiosity what are `log` and `movelog`?

Comment: StreamWriter. Just a way of me to write to file to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're removing items from the list in the Draw() call, that will give the effect you describe I think because XNA won't be running 1 Update() method for each Draw() call.

XNA tries to run Update() 60 times a second by default but the Draw() method tries to run in sync with the monitor refresh rate and will be called less if the update method takes too long.

**Edit**
it seems I was wrong about the Draw() method removing items from the array, the next step I would try while looking for the root of this problem is to make sure nothing is acting on the list out of order would be to change it to a list that logs activities.

```
public class LogList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public LogList()
            : base()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("LogList- Construction");
        }

        public new void Add(T item)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("LogList - Add");
            base.Add(item);
        }

        public new void Remove(T item)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("LogList - Remove");
            base.Remove(item);
        }

        public new void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("LogLost - RemoveAt");
            base.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        public new void Clear()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("LogList - Clear");
            base.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: My Draw just does a foreach on the List:

`foreach (int act in Fox.Actions) { ... }`

where the `...` isn't touching the list at all.

Also `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds` in Update is pretty consistently 16ms.

Comment: So at the moment you would expect your list to continue growing indefinitely?

I would suggest creating your own list class, inherit from List<int> and override the add/remove and clear methods to make sure that nothing is calling them when you don't want, you can also introduce logging to the constructor so you'll know if the list is being initialized again for some reason.

Comment: No it won't grow indefinitely. It stops at around 20/30ish.

Comment: Yes! Your logging list in addition to printing out current thread stack trace revealed that the list was getting constructed multiple times! The reason was that I was building on a mouse click and I checked for a click by doing `if (Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)` which would get triggered more than once. It didn't happen when I had breakpoints set because the breakpoint caused it to not register any more clicks.